# looking for python library which can perform levenshtein/other edit distance at word-level

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I've seen a bunch of similar questions on SO/elsewhere but none of the answers quite satisfy my needs, so I don't think this is a dup.

Also, I totally know how to implement this myself, but I'm trying not to have to re-invent the wheel.

Does anyone know any python packages which can perform levenshtein/other edit-distance comparing 2 lists of words (I've found a few), but also allow one to specify your own costs for insertion, deletion, substitution, and transpositions?

basically, I want the distances computed to be the number of edits on words in the sentences, not on the number of characters the sentences differ by.

I'm trying to replace a custom python extension module which is actually written in C, using python2's C api.  I could re-write in either pure-python or cython, but I'd rather simply add a dependency to the project.  The only problem is that this code allows one to specify your own costs for the various options, and I haven't found a package which allows this so far.

Comment: I don't see the difference, if the strings differ by n characters, then you have to change/add/delete n characters to go from stringA to stringB. Could you point out a case like that? What do you want that you don't get from `editops` from the `python-Levenshtein` library?

Comment: @Nerdrigo i want the cost to be based on operations at the word level not characters. 
 basically, I want the cost to be irrespective of the length of words.  basically I want lev("initial horizontal velocity", "horizontal velocity") to be 1 not 8

Answer (score 18):

[NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) has the function named [edit_distance](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.edit_distance.html). It calculates the Levenshtein distance between two strings. But it works good with lists of strings too:

```
import nltk

s1 = 'WAKA WAKA QB WTF BBBQ WAKA LOREM IPSUM WAKA'.split()
s2 = 'WAKA OMFG QB WTF WAKA WAKA LOREM IPSUM WAKA'.split()
print(s1)
print(s2)
print(nltk.edit_distance(s1, s2))
```

```
['WAKA', 'WAKA', 'QB', 'WTF', 'BBBQ', 'WAKA', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'WAKA']
['WAKA', 'OMFG', 'QB', 'WTF', 'WAKA', 'WAKA', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'WAKA']

2
```

Comment: thx.  I've found a few packages, although not this one, which can operation on sequence of words instead of just a sequence of chars, such as this, but none so far which allow one to pass in custom costs for the various operations as params yet.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one library which is said to be fast, and computer various types of word distance, including Levenshtein:

https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/

You should also try Hamming distance, less memory and time consuming than Levenshtein.

Comment: but it's license is not good for work...

Answer (score 0):

In case you need levenshtein token edit normalized:

```py
def token_edit_levenstein_similarity_normalized(text1: str, text2: str) -> float:
    """
    Compute the normalized levenstein distance between two texts.
    """
    import nltk
    return 1 - nltk.edit_distance(text1, text2) / max(len(text1), len(text2))
    
def test_token_edit():
    import nltk

    s1 = 'WAKA WAKA QB WTF BBBQ WAKA LOREM IPSUM WAKA'.split()
    s2 = 'WAKA OMFG QB WTF WAKA WAKA LOREM IPSUM WAKA'.split()
    print(s1)
    print(s2)
    print(nltk.edit_distance(s1, s2))
    print(token_edit_levenstein_similarity_normalized(s1, s2))
```

output

```
['WAKA', 'WAKA', 'QB', 'WTF', 'BBBQ', 'WAKA', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'WAKA']
['WAKA', 'OMFG', 'QB', 'WTF', 'WAKA', 'WAKA', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'WAKA']
2
0.7777777777777778
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fuzzywuzzy library.
It is built on top of difflib library, python-Levenshtein is used for speed.

https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/